# Material-UI: How to center pagination button?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I tried to get Pagination from Material-UI
but I want to center the buttons of the arrow and number of page.

I tried to center by creating a `<div style={{textAlign: "center"}}>` but it doesn't work because it came all in one box.

there is any way to get inside the this component and make the numbers and button to get in the center?

Comment: Are you using the pagination from the [`Table`](https://mui.com/components/tables/#custom-pagination-actions)?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [`TablePagination`](https://mui.com/api/table-pagination/#main-content), you need to remove the spacer `div` which push the pagination content to the right and set the container `justify-content` to `center`:

```
import TablePagination, {
  tablePaginationClasses
} from "@mui/material/TablePagination";
```

```
<TablePagination
  sx={{
    [`& .${tablePaginationClasses.spacer}`]: {
      display: "none"
    },
    [`& .${tablePaginationClasses.toolbar}`]: {
      justifyContent: "center"
    }
  }}
  {...}
/>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

If you're using the [`Pagination`](https://mui.com/components/pagination/#main-content) from [`DataGrid`](https://mui.com/components/data-grid/pagination/), just set the `justify-content` to `center` because the container is already flex:

```
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";
import { paginationClasses } from "@mui/material/Pagination";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    [`& .${gridClasses.footerContainer}`]: {
      justifyContent: "center"
    }
  }
});
```

```
<DataGrid pagination {...data} className={classes.root} />
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Thanks! This was really helpful with the TablePagination.

Answer (score 1):

using below code

```
<Box display="flex" justifyContent="center">
    <Pagination ... />
</Box>
```

Answer (score 0):

Their Pagination component is using `display: flex`. Adding the following style rule should achieve what you're trying to do

```css
.MuiPagination-ul { justify-content: center; }
```

Answer (score 0):

To center pagination, i suggest you wrap it inside a Grid System, then put it in the middle of two grid items with the flexGrow property equal to 1.

```
<Grid container>
  <Grid item sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}></Grid>
  <Grid item>
    <Pagination />
  </Grid>
  <Grid item sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}></Grid>
</Grid>
```